# How to install Python on CentOS without root privileges?

Tags: centos, python, root

For some reasons, I need to install Python on CentOS without root privileges. Since without root, one cannot use `yum` to install packages, so I tried

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/tools/python
make
make install
```

and it did work. However, when I was trying to install setuptools for it, by

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python - --user --insecure
```

Python complained that

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

It seems that Python was not compailed well with openssl lib. So I downloaded setuptools from its website, un-archived it, and then run

```
python setup.py install
```

and got

```
RuntimeError: Compression requires the (missing) zlib module
```

Hence, re-compile and reinstall Python is needed. This time, before I configure Python, I installed zlib, openssl and libffi manually, by adding `--prefix="$HOME/tools/foo"`, since I have no privileges to write in `/usr/foo/bar`.

After that, I tried to configure Python with flags, like `--with-zlib=$HOME/tools/zlib`. Unfortunately again, Python showed a line on the screen, that these flags are unknown. Then I tried to modify `/Modules/Setup.dist`, with expectation that I could specify the path to those libs, by uncomment the following lines:

```
#SSL=/home/foo/tools/openssl-1.0.0s
#_ssl _ssl.c \
#       -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
#       -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
......
#zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz
```

This time, things got even worse that compiling stopped by

```
./Modules/zlibmodule.c:8:18: error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
```

I searched the whole web, and found nothing. Hence, I come here and raise the question: how to install Python with zlib, openssl and libffi etc., on a CentOS, without root privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run Python + tools from your home directory.
Go to https://www.continuum.io/downloads to get Anaconda which has all of these packages listed here:
http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs including libFFI, openssl, and zlib.

Once you install, restart your terminal and wallah.  (the $PATH gets changed for you and you alone so your system's software is unaffected, and no need for emails to your administrator.)

If you need other packages that you didn't list here, you can use conda, pip, or setup.py to get more.

Go forth and be awesome.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried Anaconda today, and it works like a charm!

Comment: Upvoted for Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to install [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and then use that to install the Python version you want. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to /etc/sudoers or can you tell your administrator to add this for you? You might want to add to this file 
`username ALL = NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/apt-get , /usr/bin/aptitude, /usr/bin/whatever`
This will make it so you don't need sudo to access a file.

Comment: Yes, asking system admin for sudo privilege is indeed a solution. However, for me, I can only ask for this for a while, and after I install Python, the admin will cancel my privilege. Hence, asking temp privilege cannot solve this once and for all. : (

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for pack python with modules to anaconda-like installers - https://github.com/conda/constructor. Based on yaml config It downloading python and tools to self extracting archive which can be installed without root and internet access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standalone build from https://github.com/indygreg/python-build-standalone.

Steps to use:

```
unzstd <cpython file name>.zstd
tar -xvf <cpython file name>.tar
./python/install/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can safely install Python as a Local / Non-root user by executing the below code with the required Python Version defined in the variable "PYTHON_VER"

```
# Install Python3 and Libraries as a local user. 
python_config() {
    export PYTHON_VER="3.10.5" 
    export PYTHON_VER_SHORT="$(echo ${PYTHON_VER} | cut -d '.' -f1,2)" 
    cd ~ 
    rm -rf ~/python && mkdir -p ~/python 
    echo "" >> ~/.bashrc 
    echo "export PATH=~/python/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc 
    source ~/.bashrc 
    wget --quiet --no-check-certificate "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VER}/Python-${PYTHON_VER}.tgz" 
    tar -zxvf ~/Python-${PYTHON_VER}.tgz 1>/dev/null 
    cd ~/Python-${PYTHON_VER}/ 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - Installing in current logged-in user - $(whoami)" 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - Installation in-progress. Please wait..." 
    ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$HOME/python > /dev/null 2>&1; 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - ETA: upto 5mins. Please wait..." 
    make altinstall > /dev/null 2>&1; 
    ln -s ~/python/bin/python${PYTHON_VER_SHORT} ~/python/bin/python3 
    ln -s ~/python/bin/pip${PYTHON_VER_SHORT} ~/python/bin/pip3 
    wget --quiet --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O - | python3 - --prefix=$HOME/python 
    source ~/.bashrc 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pygithub 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 install --upgrade --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt --use-pep517 
    cd ~ && rm -rf ~/Python-${PYTHON_VER}* 
    ~/python/bin/python3 --version 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 --version 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - Setup Completed!" 
}

# Function Call
python_config
```